# Why my TCP client stop recv() when there's no send() executed

Tags: c, tcp, recv

I have a client that looks like this:

```
struct sockaddr_in dest_addr;
dest_addr.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr(host_ip);
dest_addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
dest_addr.sin_port = htons(PORT);
addr_family = AF_INET;
ip_protocol = IPPROTO_IP;

int sock = socket(addr_family, SOCK_STREAM, ip_protocol);
/*
   connect() handle block
   connect successfully
*/

int state = AWAKE;
while(1){
    if(state == AWAKE){
        int err_socket = sendto(sock, message, strlen(message), 0, (struct sockaddr *)&dest_addr, sizeof(dest_addr));
    }

    int len = recv(sock, rx_buffer, sizeof(rx_buffer) - 1, 0);
    if(len<0){
        ESP_LOGE(TCP_TAG, "Error occurred during recving: errno %d", errno); --> error 11
        continue;
    }
    
    if(strcmp(rx_buffer, "ON") == 0){
        state == AWAKE;
    }else if(strcmp(rx_buffer, "OFF") == 0){
        state == SLEEPING;
    }
}
```

After receiving the "OFF" message, the state will switch to SLEEPING and stop sending messages to the server, but keep receiving messages.

However, when I switch the state to SLEEPING, the recv result will always return -1 while the server keeps sending messages to the client.

My questions is, do it always need send() and recv() as a peer?

Comment: Note that you don't send a null-terminator for `message`. Do you receive one? If not then you can't use `rx_buffer` as a string.

Comment: As for `recv` returning `-1`, please check the actual error it reports, which is stored in `errno` (or returned by `WSAGetLastError()` in winsock).

Comment: By the way, you seem to be misunderstanding something basic about TCP (`SOCK_STREAM` sockets). TCP is a *connected* protocol. Clients needs to call `connect` to be connected to the server. You *must* connect to the server, and then use plain `send` instead of `sendto`.

Comment: And ***always*** check for and handle errors, something which you seem to be missing right now.

Comment: Thanks for your comments.
please ignore the message and rx_buffer, I just didn't write down the full definition. There's no problem with it.

I see the errno is 11. It means "No more processes", I think it represents timeout.
The only thing I confuse is that only when I jump over send(), the recv() will get nothing.
So probably send and recv need to execute by sequence?

Comment: On Linux `11` means `EAGAIN`. which means you have a non-blocking socket and there simply isn't anything to read from it currently, and that you should try again later. I suggest you use `select` with an infinite delay to return when the socket is ready to read something from again. Any decent network programming tutorial (like [Beej's Guide to Network Programming](https://beej.us/guide/bgnet/)) should have all the information you need.

Answer (score 1):

> After receiving "OFF" message, the state will switch to SLEEPING

No, actually it doesn't, because you are mistakenly using the `==` comparison operation where you should be using the `=` assignment operator. So, your `state` doesn't actually change value.

Even if that were not the case, your `rx_buffer` is not null-terminated, so your `strcmp()` calls won't work correctly.

> However, when I switch the state to SLEEPING, the recv result will always return -1 while the server keeps sending messages to the client.

That means `recv()` is failing. You need to then look at `errno` to find out why. Which, according to your comments, is 11 (`EAGAIN`), which simply means that the socket is operating in non-blocking mode and there is nothing available to read from the socket at that exact moment, so just try again later. This is not a fatal error.

However, an error condition that you are not handling at all is when `recv()` returns 0 on peer disconnect. You need to stop your loop in that situation and close your socket.

> do it always need send() and recv() as a peer?

No. TCP is birectional. You can treat the socket as send-only or recv-only, if that is what your protocol requires. Though, do make sure you read from the socket periodically in order to catch peer disconnects and network failures.